# Troubleshooting utility or resources for Windows 10 1803 Update BSODs?

Tags: bsod, windows-10-upgrade

After the Windows 10 1803 update, I started seeing random BSODs.  This was not a problem prior to the update. After trying the Windows 10 Troubleshooting tools and going through the recommendations on the forums, I am still getting a BSOD every 5 to 10 minutes.

The commands:

SFC /SCANNOW

DISM /Online /cleanup-image /restore-health

Report no problems.

The Microsoft Bluescreen Troubleshooter finds no issues.

The Bluescreen Viewer from NirSoft points to NTOSKRNL.EXE but I don't see a specific driver that caused the crash.

This seems to indicate that the 1803 updates are not compatible with one or more of the drivers on the machine.

Are there any third-party tools that can be used to determine the drivers?  Also are there any ways to "ghost" the applications and data on the machine to an External Drive so that they may be used on another PC?

This PC has never recovered from the initial 1803 update.

Are there any diagnostic tools or procedures that can detect issues that are not found by the Windows 10 Troubleshooting Utilities?

Comment: [analyze the crash dumps with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) to see what is wrong

Comment: don't use this BluescreenViewer bullshit use Windbg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the symptoms, this is almost definitely a driver issue. You should restart into safemode and explore updating drivers from there. I'd start with your sound drivers as there were some fairly significant changes to how sound works in the 1803 upgrade.

To access safe mode in Windows 10, hold down the `shift` key while clicking `Restart`. You should get a trouble-shooting screen with several options. You want `Start-up Settings` which can typically be found under `Troubleshoot`. From there simply press `5` to restart in safe mode with networking enabled.

This will give you access to windows with most of your hardware drivers disabled (using generic drivers for video) and still have internet access. Then check with the manufacturer of your hardware to see if any of them have updated drivers.

Comment: This was a driver issue - this was caused by using the latest Windows 10 1803 updates with the latest NVIDIA GTX 970 drivers.  When I rolled back the NVIDIA Drivers, the Blue Screens stopped.  This took a number of days to diagnose.  There does not seem to be any "official" acknowledgment  from Microsoft on the 1803 issues.   This update was a catastrophe.